# showDocument() does not display new window in IE8 with Java 7/Java 6u27

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet

I have a Java Applet that interacts with the Java Plugin to show a document (just a URL) in a named browser window:

```
public class TestApplet extends Applet {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();

        final JButton showButton = new JButton("Show Google!");

        showButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("http://google.com"), "Some Window Title");
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        add(showButton);
    }
}
```

This has worked historically but starting with Java 7 and Java 6u27, the window fails to open in Internet Explorer (tested in IE 8).  If I use `_blank` as the window title (target) instead of `Google`, the window opens correctly (albeit in a new window each  time).

I've tracked down this bug that was fixed for 6u27:

- [Vista/IE7 further showDocument focus issue with named targeted windows](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6991343)

Has anybody else experienced the same behaviour?  Have you found a workaround (other than using "_blank")?

### Edit

Updated the example.  I wasn't actually using "Google" as the target, I was using "Some Window Title" (sorry!).  It seems like this problem is unique to targets with spaces in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like this problem is unique to targets with spaces in the name.

Two possible solutions:

1. Replace the " " with "%20"
2. **Don't use a space in the name of the target!**  (Though I thought that would be a 'no brainer'.)

Comment: I was hoping for an environment change (like an IE setting) but didn't find one.  These weren't static target names being used, our code was a library function for displaying documents so our solution was a search-and-replace on the window title supplied to us.  IIRC we tried URL-encoding the space but with no luck.

Comment: Just for some extra context, it wasn't just spaces that weren't allowed but also some symbols (at the very least `.` was prohibited).  An interesting find is that trying to open a window via Javascript with the same target name would also fail in IE8, leaving me to wonder why it ever *did* work in previous versions of the Java plugin.  Did they previously manually strip out the bad characters? Anyway I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it should work.

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        desktop.browse(new URI(info));
```